# Combining normals

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, normals

I have two textures, one that goes to a bump node and one that goes to a normal map node, so just to clarify one is black and white and the other is a normal texture. I was wondering how I could combine both of these together to form one normal. If anybody has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you have only one normal map, this is easy:
[image: node graph using the bump node's normal input]

The bump map includes a "normal" input where you can supply a normal to apply the bump map offset to. By default this just uses the mesh normal, but you can plug a normal map there instead. You can also chain multiple bump nodes together this way if you like.

If you have two normal maps, it gets more complicated, see the answers here for a variety to methods: [How to Combine two Normal Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps)