# how to add scratches to a low poly sword in geometry?

Tags: modeling

So I am trying to add scratches to a low poly sword and I don't know how to do it properly? Tried to use sculpt mode but I don't have enough geometry.

Comment: Hello, maybe fake it with a normal or bump map?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82472/how-to-add-scratches https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/how-to-make-dirty-looking-object http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=metal+scratches

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?