# Trouble adding two normal maps to an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, normal-map

I'm having trouble adding two normal maps to a leather seat. I'm using the principled shader and each normal map has it's own uv map. When I add the second normal map it adds unwanted distortion.

[image: Node set up 1]

[image: Result 1]

[image: Node set up 2]

[image]

Comment: If you switch the normal maps does that work? What about specifying the maps in the field on the normal map nodes? I seem to recall that connecting a normal map to the displacement output gives incorrect results. Maybe try adding the two maps together with the vector math node and doing it that way.

Comment: You are pluging normal output (3 channels) into greyscale imput (1 channel). Here is solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps, did you try to google it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question and I cant even explain what is going on but maybe this can help you.

Since I cant explain this answer I will take it down if I get yelled at or downvoted. lol

This is for using 2 normal maps (or more):

[image]

[image]

I have never plugged a normal map directly into displacement socket. I don't know if that is causing the problem or not.

I attached the .blend file so you can just append the node tree if you want.

[image]

Comment: @ icYou520 - Thank you! I tried that already and it didn't work for me. My guess so far is that it's something to do with the principled shader and/or the two different maps.