# Is possible to use 2 normal maps on the same model?

Tags: texturing

I can use to texture a model the normal map of the model and also the normal map of the material/texture ?(This is correct or i am thinking  wrong?).

FOR EXAMPLE :
I have a brick and a coppy it to create details ,some cracks,and than i create a normal map.I waht to add also a texture(normal map) to give a porous look.Is this possible?

Comment: Depend on how you want your normal maps work with each other. In theory, you can combine those maps directly with the value store inside it. Since it is a vector indicating the normal direction in that spot.

Comment: you should give an example because it's a little bit imprecise, but it looks like you can simply mix 2 Image Textures with your normal map pictures with a Color node > MixRGB > Overlay or Mix or another mode then plug into the Normal Map, as explained here by Rico Cilliers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps

Comment: Most of the answers are not really accurate. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100885/combine-two-normal-maps-and-control-the-strength-of-each the last answer here by Secrop is more accurate. Rotations need to be added on top of each other, therefore combining normal maps is not as simple as it may seem.