# Make Normals "brighter"

Tags: texturing, normals, normal-map

I am currently looking for a way to make normals "brighter".

The reason is that I was looking for a method to combine two normal maps and found this question: [How to Combine two Normal Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
I implemented all of the described techniques and two of them deliver the same result but the second one is a bit brighter. I wanted to make the first one look like this too.

First one:
[image: Normal Map 1]
Second one:
[image: Normal Map 2]

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Actually it's the other way around. The second method seems to brighten the color.

EDIT: For clarification the first method is the one by redcapricorn / Secrop and the second one by Bithur.
I think it might appear brighter because Bithur divided with an HSV Value of 1.25 but I don't know how to enter anything beyond 1.

Comment: first you should ask why the final materialis brighter. Maybe you just have a slighly different lightsource or orientation, or your normalmap is just not normalized, or somehow offset. Check those things and add information to your question. Also add images of the actual normalmaps and not of the final material

Comment: @HenrikD You actually delivered the answer, I normalized the second one and now it's fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Normalmap is not Normalized. Normalize your Normalmap to get correct results.