# Overlay, dirt with principled BSDF

Tags: shaders

I've got a very clean aluminum metal texture with It's own roughness, metalness, normal etc-texture on a principled shader. It's nice but I want it dirtier.

So I've downloaded some dirt overlays and metal scufs from Poliigon... but I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to use them on the Principled shader. No matter how I try to MIX RGB and such it doesn't look right.

Please help!

Comment: Without seeing what you're seeing, it's hard to help. Include some images that show what you're dealing with, how you've tried to solve your situation, and maybe also one or two images that show the end result you're after. That way you'll get much more to the point help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sREos49gtTo
10:49
BlenderGuru's video, he gives the link to a Normal Map node group mixer. It's incredible and works like a charm,

Answer (score 2):

Combine your existing Roughness map with your new Dirt/Scuffs map using a *Math* node with Type = "Maximum". Use the output of the *Math* node for your Principled shader's roughness socket.

[image]

Comment: Woohoo!! That's was a quick reply!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I'll be super honest: I haven't tried it with actual textures. It should work in principle though: let me know!

Comment: Works great with roughness but not when really combining the the normals...

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know you also had Normals. They are a bit more difficult to combine: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll have a look at that thread then. Thanks again!