# How do I bake both the paint texture and sculpted effects into one normal?

Tags: unity

Right now I have a sculpted texture that I used a method I learned on youtube to bake. You have a low poly version of your object and a high poly sculpted version right on top and bake the high poly effects onto the low poly which gives you a normal map. Now I want to begin painting my object however have a question.

**How would I go about baking the paint texture part of my object (like effect of wood or stone)?**

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you, i think you have to bake both as normal maps separately, and then save the images that you got and then open a image editor like photoshop or gimp and then set to overlay mode the first layer and then join them and export it to png or other image format, and then setup the normal in your node editor.

Comment: Overlay mostly works but is not mathematically correct.  There are better (but also more complicated) ways to combine normal maps.  Also, you can do Overlay (and the other methods) directly in Blender if you're ok with the hassle of additional nodes.

Comment: complicated ways like?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps - if I understood it all myself I'd make it a full answer, but this is probably a good place to start.