# Using partial normal maps for character wrinkles

Tags: normal-map

I can't seem to find any solid way to do this online.  I'm trying to have wrinkles on skin during animation.  Baking a static normal map on mesh will not do the job because I only want certain areas to have it and I only want it during animation.

Perfect example is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aRPr7ftUgg

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe do it with Shapekeys? In that case you'll probably need to add a bit of topology to your forehead

Comment: I think this is about combining Normal maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate shader values like any other property in Blender.  Just right click and insert a keyframe.  Or, for better control, add a [driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#shape-key-drivers) based on an animated control.

[image]

Comment: This is will let you control the entire normal map as whole which is not exactly want I want.  I have one normal map for the entire character.  That has the same strength.  I want wrinkles to form on the face when deformations happen.  I can't put that on the static normal map that is baked in.  Those need to be different material.

Comment: Please can you edit your post to explain exactly what you need then.  If you need to merge multiple normal maps check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps