# Issues with normals to create more depth

Tags: texturing, shaders, normals, bump

I wanted to create a displacement to create something like this. I have a existing metal texture applied to the object.
[image]

This is how it looks like now [image]

I have included my shading editor for more information
[image]

*Update*This is with the displacement.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can have a result such as the one you show, you'll probably need to model it

Comment: Hello :). You're mixing terms a little. Title says *normals*, body says *displacement* and node setup shows *bump* node. What type of map do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can get there using *Displacement* on a higly subdivided mesh.
Bump and Normal maps are faster, but will only get you so far.

[image]

Choose either *Displacement only* or *Bump only* depending on your needs.
[image]

Comment: Hi @JachymMichal
First of all, thank you for your time in answering my question. I really appreciate your help.

I have tried the method for displacement and I think it's what I'm hoping to achieve. But when I'm applying to a cylindrical shape object, it distorts the object quite a fair bit, is there a reason why? 

I have added an image in the original post above.

Comment: I just realized, so don't mind if I just add on a little, it seems like I have to subdivide the object quite a fair bit. Thus, it causes the program to lag a little. Is this the right way or it's just my CPU or GPU's limitation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mix two normal maps, take a look at this question, which explains very well how to do it: [How to Combine two Normal Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps).

However, to create a more visible bump effect, try to use the **Bump** node, and plug the bump map into the **Height** socket, as here:

[image: result]

I think this setup gives you more control via **Strength** and **Distance** values. You can also plug your normal map into the **Normal** socket, it's up to you. Just remember to set **Non-color** for bump and normal maps.