# Normal Node Causing Flat Shaded Polys

Tags: texturing, shaders, normals

Why might I be getting flat shaded poly's here? My model is smooth shaded (no hard edges, etc). There's not image texture on the Normal node which is usually where I see this problem come up; the image texture is not set to 'non-color' or 'linear'. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: We need to see inside the node groups, or, preferably, to see a file so that we can look inside the node groups ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to diagnose from here.

In this screenshot we're looking at the result of this node:

[image]

but there's a lot of Normal vector data being passed around all over the place.

There are a few posts on this site detailing [how to mix Normal Maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps), and by my estimation you are running into one or more of the problems discussed there.

You say you aren't using an *Image Texture* so I assume you're generating everything procedurally with Blender's built in nodes.  What I would do is work with the black and white data and pass it along the node tree until the very end right before the *Principled BSDF* and put the *Normal Map* node there.

My supposition is that Normal Map data is currently being added using *Vector Math* -> *Add* and this magnifies the blue channel such that it can't properly interpolate down to a value that makes sense anymore... Idk if that makes sense.