# Add Scratches and Dents to downloaded material (node tree has no input for normals)

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map, shader-nodes

I downloaded a material pack from blendermarket and after mixing 2 materials (worn out edges) I tried to add scratches and dents, but the Materials I bought are not having a slot for adding normal maps. I will attach a photo of the node tree of the material.
Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

I am aware how to add normal maps to a normal material that is managed by a Princ BSDF but this bought material has no slot and when I add another material to mix it with mine it overtakes the color, so I know I must be just some clicks away from a solution, but I can't figure it out...

[image: Details I want to add]

[image: nodes for details]

[image: Node Tree from bought material]

[image: close_up from node tree settings]

[image]

Comment: 1st pic shows the details i wanna add --- 
2nd the nodes of this details --- 
3rd is node tree of bought material --- 
4th is details of this node tree --- 
5th details of the main settings of this node tree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Combine two Normal Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but i basically have the problem where to add the normal maps i created. therefore i posted screens of the node trees. i bet it must be something really easy, but i cant find the right node setting

Comment: Or i figure a way out, how to not take over the color of a shader I use for mixing. tried to add a diffuse or transparent shader but had not the results i wished for. the bought material is great, just want to combine it a new normal map but I cant figure out where to connect them (see pictures of Node Tree)